# Draw more than one draggable line inside the panel control

Tags: c#, winforms, draw, drag

```
namespace DraggableControls
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private Control activeControl;
        private Point previousLocation;

        void txt1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            activeControl = sender as Control;
            previousLocation = e.Location;
            Cursor = Cursors.Hand;            
        }
        void txt1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            activeControl = null;
            Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        }
        void txt1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (activeControl == null || activeControl != sender)
                return;
            Point location = activeControl.Location;
            location.Offset(e.Location.X - previousLocation.X, 
                            e.Location.Y - previousLocation.Y);
            activeControl.Location = location;
            DrawLine(txt1.Location, txt2.Location, panel1);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txt1.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(txt1_MouseDown);
            txt1.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(txt1_MouseMove);
            txt1.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(txt1_MouseUp);


            txt3.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(txt3_MouseDown);
            txt3.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(txt3_MouseMove);
            txt3.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(txt3_MouseUp);
        }



        void txt3_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            activeControl = sender as Control;
            previousLocation = e.Location;
            Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
        }
        void txt3_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            activeControl = null;
            Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        }
        void txt3_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (activeControl == null || activeControl != sender)
                return;
            Point location = activeControl.Location;
            location.Offset(e.Location.X - previousLocation.X, 
                            e.Location.Y - previousLocation.Y);
            activeControl.Location = location;
            DrawLine(txt3.Location, txt4.Location, panel1);
        }

        public void DrawLine(Point start, Point end, Panel ctrl)
        {
            ctrl.Refresh();
            Pen P = new Pen(Color.Red, 3);
            P.StartCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.NoAnchor;
            P.CustomEndCap = 
              new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.AdjustableArrowCap(4, 8, false);
            ctrl.CreateGraphics().DrawLine(P, start, end);
            ctrl.PerformLayout();
            ctrl.CreateGraphics().Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

I want draw a draggable TextBox and link two TextBoxes. In this code I can drag a TextBox but the link between two lines is not properly working.

Comment: You also nee to code the Paint event and its e.Graphics object; the result of the DrawLine method is non-persistant. (Plus: the disposal code is missing and/or wrong..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The `DrawLine` code is off with wrong and/or missing `Dispose` and
- Your code is quite redundant

Here is a suggestion; first let's clean up the `DrawLine` code with proper `using` clauses.:

```
    public void DrawLine(Point start, Point end, Control ctrl)
    {
        ctrl.Refresh();
        using ( Graphics g = activeControl.CreateGraphics())
        using ( Pen P = new Pen(Color.Red, 3) )
        {
          P.StartCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.NoAnchor;
          P.CustomEndCap = 
            new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.AdjustableArrowCap(4, 8, false);
          g.DrawLine(P, start, end);
        }
    }
```

Aside: Note that this is one of the rare cases where you want to use `control.CreateGraphics()`; the resulting graphics are non-persistent, i.e. they will disappear whener the system redraws the Form, , but that is just what we want here..

Next let's make the mouse events generic:

```
void txt_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    activeControl = sender as Control;
    previousLocation = e.Location;
    Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
}

void txt_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    activeControl = null;
    Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    panel1.Invalidate();
}

void txt_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (activeControl == null || activeControl != sender)
        return;
    Control tgtCtl = activeControl.Tag as Control;  // check the..
    if (tgtCtl == null) return;                     // target!

    Point location = activeControl.Location;
    location.Offset(e.Location.X - previousLocation.X, 
                    e.Location.Y - previousLocation.Y);
    activeControl.Location = location;

    DrawLine(location, tgtCtl.Location, activeControl.Parent);
}
```

Finally we prepare by hooking **both** `TextBoxes` to the same generic events and telling each, which other `TextBox` will be its target by setting its `Tag`:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txt1.Tag = txt2;
    txt3.Tag = txt4;

    txt1.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(txt_MouseDown);
    txt1.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(txt_MouseMove);
    txt1.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(txt_MouseUp);

    txt3.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(txt_MouseDown);
    txt3.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(txt_MouseMove);
    txt3.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(txt_MouseUp);

    .. 
  }
```

Also note how I made the `Panel` generic by drawing on `activeControl.Parent`, which could be anything..

Comment: But when I drag the texbox the pen is once again redrawing the line. I just want to change the dynamic start and end location for the line when I drag the textbox.

Comment: Oh, do you mean the line shall only be visible while you move a TextBox and then disappear?? For this you simply insert a `panel1.Invalidate();` at the end of the MouseUp events. See the updates answer, which does away with the redundancy..